# Unity vuforia plugin's QCAR Behavior causes hang time

Tags: ipad, unity-game-engine, vuforia, qcar-sdk

My AR project, which runs at a solid 30 fps on my five year old iPad 2, has a huge hang time when enabling or disabling the QCAR Behavior (with all the AR functionality) in Vuforia. The whole app freezes for 10 seconds or so in the editor. This lag does not occur as badly on the device, but it's still there. After it happens the framerate is fine -- but is there any way to deal with this hang time? Has anyone else experienced it? Any help would be appreciated! I'm using the latest Unity 4.6, and the latest Vuforia AR plugin, downloaded yesterday. I'm running the editor on a macbook air, though my friend with a macbook pro experiences it as well. Anybody else getting this?

Comment: Yeah, I've felt it too. Are you using `Continuous Baking` in Lighting or `Multithreading` in the build?

Comment: There's no lighting in my scene. I'm not sure where multithreading is turned on or off in the build process -- I don't see any options for it in the Player Settings.

Comment: @blackmorningus Do you mean that you worked around it in your project?

Comment: No, so far all my apps take pretty long. But I guess that's cause Vuforia in itself is heavy. But I guess reducing your Bake settings could move it faster?

Comment: We'll try that. Thanks!